# Format and replace a phone number using Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to validate a phone number on a user register/edit form. There are two fields: phone number 1 and phone number 2. They might come filled or not. If they come filled, I'll have to extract its numbers and, using a regular expression, format it correctly and display it so the user can edit. The problem is I'm a beginner and I'm not managing to format it. Here follows the code:

```
if (!empty($phone_1 )) {
    $string = $phone_1;
    $newString = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/i', '', $string); //extract numbers

    $regex = '^(11 [9][0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4})|(\(1[2-9]\) [5-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(\      ([2-9][1-9]\) [5-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})$';
    $final = preg_replace($regex, '', $newString);
  }
```

The format that I'm trying to output is "99 99999.9999".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `sub_str` to format your string ?

```
$phone1="01234567890";
$phone1 = substr($phone1, 0, 2) . ' ' . substr($phone1, 2, 5) . '.' . substr($phone1, 7, 4);
echo $phone1;
```

Output :

```
01 23456.7890
```

Comment: I don't know how come I did not consider using sub_str. Thank you!

Comment: @user3816423 And I don't know how come you though about regex ! It feel likes using a hammer to write an essay.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regex you can use this:

```
^(\d\d)(\d{5})(\d{4})$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/jT3pU1/1)**

[image]

The code you can use is:

```
$re = "/^(\\d\\d)(\\d{5})(\\d{4})$/"; 
$str = "01234567890"; 
$subst = '\1 \2.\3'; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you! This made very clear to me what the second parameter of "preg_replace" is for.

Comment: @user3816423 glad to help :) . If you question is solved you might consider marking an answer to close your question.